# Audit for DISABLE/ENABLE Triggers IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need a way to audit when someone attempts to either ENABLE or DISABLE a trigger in our database. The DDL trigger alternative works great but only under the condition for when the user uses

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> ENABLE TRIGGER <triggerName>
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> DISABLE TRIGGER <triggerName>
```

statement. From what I have determined, the DDL method renders useless if the user executes the following statements that bypass the ALTER command:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER <triggerName> ON <tableName>
ENABLE TRIGGER <triggerName> ON <tableName>
```

I have had several thoughts on capturing these events none of them work. One of which was if I could access the table underlying the sys.triggers view, I could place an insert/update trigger on that table and filter on the trigger name to acquire the audit; but my suspicion is that it would likely lead to an infinite recursion even if it were possible to do.

Does anyone here have any possible suggestions for alternative solutions to this problem? I don't understand why MS would allow enhanced versions of statements to escape the scope of audits. That is, auditing from the most simplest methods; using SQL profiler seems to be unneccesary overhead for this.

Comment: Wow - are you saying that the ENABLE TRIGGER ... ON ... syntax bypasses SQL 2008 DDL Audit? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Just DML triggers presumably as if someone can disable DDL triggers they can also disable your audit trigger? This is recorded in the default trace I think.

Comment: Yes, if someone were to disable my DML trigger using the syntax DISABLE TRIGGER <triggerName> ON <tableName> then I would have no way to capture that event via a DDL trigger.

Comment: @Mark - Yes. I just tried setting up a trigger on `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS` and it didn't fire on `DISABLE TRIGGER`. What edition are you on? Is SQL Server Audit available? If not I think you may need to look at tracing or extended events.

Comment: We are running SQL 2008 R2 but I'm not certain if SQL Server Audit is available. But if it were (which I can inquire), from BOL it appears that automatic auditing isn't available unless you're running Enterprise. Also, I did look into SQL Server Audit Groups prior and it doesn't appear that it captures the type of event I am after when the DISABLE or ENABLE event is fired using the statements I am targeting to capture. Is this not correct?

Comment: When DDL triggers first came out, they missed some key stuff like sp_rename. This seems like another miss to me. Is there a Connect item?

Comment: Yes, I'm in agreement with you on that Aaron; but what do you mean by "A Connect item"??? Lost me a bit.

Comment: @Mark - [There is a connect item but it looks as though it was closed in error](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/434951/ddl-trigger-still-not-working-disable-trigger-is-this-not-an-event). The Microsoft Response says that you have to use `ALTER TABLE` to disable a trigger which is clearly not the case. (But then there is [another connect item closed as Won't Fix](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/509242/fire-a-ddl-trigger-when-the-new-syntax-disable-trigger-is-executed) )

Comment: Thanks Martin, apparently MS seemed to acknowledge this as a possible issue only as the submitter pressed the point; then Closed as Won't Fix after the pressure was off from the submitter with their apparent expectation that MS would address the problem. NOT!!! So typical of the support in some areas where not enough folks complain to merit the fix. Very unfortunate though. I will obviously have to find another method of audit but triggers won't be applicable in this scenario. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 6):

I would first address this through permissions. No one except a few dbas should have alter table permissions on prod and thus cannot use enable or disable trigger. If an application is using it, that should stop it. There is no excuse for any user to need to alter tables. If you want to do that, you probaly have a design flaw. If you have people actualy disabling triggers, you definitely have a design flaw. Any code with disable trigger in it should be a huge red flag during a code review. It should be unacceptable to disable a trigger in application code. This is something that should only be done by dbas who have the experience to know when to do it. If you are writing application code and seem to need to disable a trigger to get your code to work, then your code is incorrect or the trigger needs to be rewritten, disabling triggers should only happen in the rarest of cases.

Comment: I wish I could upvote again. SQL is not broken because you can't audit folks disabling triggers, policy is broken because people who aren't trusted have too much power.

Comment: While everyone is rightly entitled to their own opinions and I also agree that governance of the system is equally important; I strongly disagree that the inability to audit this type of event as not being a flaw. To say that would be to imply that the ability to audit the identical event albeit, with different syntax is a luxury as opposed to a security tool. Otherwise, why not simply remove the auditing of triggers from the DDL model altogether? Another side point to this is that be it a flaw to the governance policies or not; knowing who is executing events on your system an imperative.

Comment: I agree it's a flaw, but allowing people the rights to do such things is a larger flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Since the For anyone who comes across this thread when searching for trigger auditing help, the following may be of use.  This was used in SQL Server 2019.  Link at the bottom provided for reference.

```sql
USE master;
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT MyAudit 
  TO FILE (FILEPATH = 'C:\temp\', MAXSIZE = 1 GB) 
  WITH (ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE); 
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT MyAudit WITH (STATE = ON); 
GO

USE [your_database];
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION schema_db_change 
  FOR SERVER AUDIT MyAudit 
  ADD (SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP), 
  ADD (DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP);

ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION schema_db_change WITH (STATE = ON); 
GO
```

Now go and disable your trigger, and then run:

```
SELECT event_time, succeeded, server_principal_name, [object_name], [statement] 
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file ('C:\Temp\MyAudit*', NULL, NULL);
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27255/when-was-a-table-trigger-disabled-and-re-enabled